# Variable definition in wave function for scattering particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, definition

For the wave function of a scattered particle when finding the scattering aptitude we have:

$$\psi(r)=Ae^{ik_0∙r}+\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^2} ∫G(r-r')V(r')\psi(r')d^3r'$$

I was wondering what the variables $r$ and $r'$ represent. I think r just represents the position of the particle and $r'$ the size of the detector, but this seems wrong. I say this as when we do the Born approximation on it we substitute the $r'$ for e.g. $r_1$
. So what do they actually represent? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable $r$ represents the position in space at which you wish to evaluate the wave function $\psi$. This is indicated by $\psi(r)$.

The variable $r'$ is a spatial integration variable. It represents the points at which you are integrating the function $GV\psi$.

An analogy to electrostatics might help. When you want to evaluate the electric potential $V$ at a point $r$ due to some charge distribution $\rho$, you do

$$V(r)=k\int \frac{\rho(r')}{\left|\vec r-\vec r'\right|}dr'.$$

The variable $r'$ represents points where there's some contribution from your charge distribution to your electric potential.

Likewise, in your QM example, the variable $r'$ represents points where there's a contribution from the potential (and other causes) to the wave function itself.